# Specify required base class for .NET attribute targets

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, custom-attributes

I tried to create a custom .NET attribute with the code below but accidentally left off the subclass.  This generated an easily-fixed compiler error shown in the comment.

```
// results in compiler error CS0641: Attribute 'AttributeUsage' is 
// only valid on classes derived from System.Attribute
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
internal class ToolDeclarationAttribute
{
    internal ToolDeclarationAttribute()
    {
    }
}
```

My question is how does the compiler know the `[AttributeUsage]` attribute can only be applied to a subclass of `System.Attribute`?  Using .NET Reflector I don't see anything special on the `AttributeUsageAttribute` class declaration itself.  Unfortunately this might just be a special case generated by the compiler itself.

```
[Serializable, ComVisible(true), AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited=true)]
public sealed class AttributeUsageAttribute : Attribute
{
    ...
```

I would like to be able to specify that my custom attribute can only be placed on subclasses of a particular class (or interface).  Is this possible?

Comment: This restriction is sometimes a sign you should be using a marker Interface instead. It performs the same functions, except when you need to pass class-level metadata as a parameter. So if instances can just as easily provide say, a count of something, the interface can require a public property getting that. If it has to be class-level, you're stuck with Attributes.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> I would like to be able to specify that my custom attribute can only be placed on subclasses of a particular class (or interface). Is this possible?

Actually, there is a way to do this for subclasses (but not interfaces) using `protected` - see [Restricting Attribute Usage](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/06/restricting-attribute-usage.html). To reproduce the code (but not the discussion):

```
abstract class MyBase {
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    protected sealed class SpecialAttribute : Attribute {}
}
class ShouldBeValid : MyBase {
    [Special] // works fine
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
class ShouldBeInvalid { // not a subclass of MyBase
    [Special] // type or namespace not found
    [MyBase.Special] // inaccessible due to protection level
    public int Bar{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Excellent thanks!  To be honest I never considered doing this until I got the compiler error but I will definitely your solution.

Answer (score 2):

`AttributeUsageAttribute` is just a magic class (like `Attribute` itself is). This is a built-in compiler rule, and you cannot do something like that for your own attributes.

Answer (score 1):

With ReSharper you can use `[JetBrains.Annotations.BaseTypeRequired(typeof(YouBaseType))]`