# How to make .NET attribute only valid on certain types

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Specify required base class for .NET attribute targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190649/specify-required-base-class-for-net-attribute-targets)

I want to specify that my custom attribute only be valid on certain types (based on interface or base class).
Like this:

[image: attributes]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create an `Attribute` which can only be applied to certain types in much the way that `AttributeUsage` can only be applied to types deriving from `Attribute`.  Introducing this type of custom restriction is simply not possible.  The particular error you're seeing is not because of a custom restriction, it's one that's simply hard wired into the compiler itself.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can, you can only specify on which kind of language element the attribute is valid. `AttributeUsageAttribute` is a special case, because the compiler is aware of it and doesn't let you apply it on something that is not an attribute