# How restrict attribute on interface's method

Tags: c#

I'd like to create a custom attribute but restrict its usage to interface's methods. Is it possible to do that in C#?

I'd like to have compilator error when I try to do this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
   [MyAttribute]
   public void SomeMethod() { ... }
}

[MyAttribute]
public interface IMyInterface { ... }
```

I want to be be able to do only this:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
   [MyAttribute]
   void SomeMethod();
}
```

I can limit my attribute to interface or to methods but not both in the same time

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
```

Comment: Could you give an example of which restriction are you want to apply?

Comment: Is there no code or examples. Please pad your answer out a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. Have a look at the [AttributeTargets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributetargets%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) enum. You can limit it to a method, but not for a method *of an interface*.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved for subclasses but not interfaces. See this question:
[Specify required base class for .NET attribute targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190649/specify-required-base-class-for-net-attribute-targets)

Answer (score 1):

No. You can not. Check AttributeTarget enum at MSDN.