# Is is possible to confine attribute usage for a custom attribute to classes of a certain type/supertype only?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

The title pretty much asks it all. I have an attribute that I would like to be confined to be used only on `ApiFunction` derived classes. Is this in any way achievable sort of checking the target type in the attribute constructor and throwing an error if all is not right?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190649/specify-required-base-class-for-net-attribute-targets and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959863/how-to-make-net-attribute-only-valid-on-certain-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, an attribute is not provided with information about the code element it is applied to. You will need to have a method that examines each type/method in your library to ensure that the attribute is only placed on allowed items.

You can implement *nearly* the feature you are after by creating an MSBuild task that runs after the build process to validate the compiled assembly, allowing you to produce your own compile-time errors if the attribute is misused.

Comment: +1 Cool idea using MSBuild tasks. Of course, this would not prevent third parties from misusing your attribute (by removing or disabling the MSBuild task), but it might be helpful within a team environment for internal software.